# React Native loop this

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

when I put `onPress` in a map loop, it doesn't work. how to fix it?

```
var PageOne = React.createClass({
  _handlePress() {
    this.props.navigator.push({id: 2,});
  },
  render () {
      return (
        <View>          
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={this._handlePress}> //work here 
          <Text> One </Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
          <View style={styles.albums}>
          {
            list.map(function(item, index){
              return (
                <TouchableOpacity key={index} onPress={this._handlePress}> //doesn't work hehre
                  <Text>{item}</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
              )
            })
          }
            </View>
      </View>
      );
  }
});
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`this` is referring to the wrong context, you need the scope to be lexically bound, which is what the fat arrow function will do for you.

Try calling your function like this:

```
onPress={ () => this._handlePress() }
```

Also, you need to bind the map function to the correct context like this:

```
<View style={styles.albums}>
  {
    list.map(function(item, index){
       return (
         <TouchableOpacity key={index} onPress={() => this._handlePress()}> 
           <Text>{item}</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
       )
     }.bind(this))
   }
</View>
```

Or like this:

```
<View style={styles.albums}>
  {
    list.map((item, index) => {
       return (
         <TouchableOpacity key={index} onPress={() => this._handlePress()}> 
           <Text>{item}</Text>
         </TouchableOpacity>
       )
     })
   }
</View>
```

I set up a working project [here](https://rnplay.org/apps/_PmG6Q).

https://rnplay.org/apps/_PmG6Q

Comment: thanks for your answer, but get a error `undefined' is not an object (evaluating '_this._handlePress')` :(