# React Native Pass Parent Method to Child Component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, ecmascript-6

I am trying to pass method from my parent component to child component. My code is correct i think but still it shows the error **undefined is not an object(evaluating '_this2.props.updateData')** . I don't know whats the issue because i searched the internet a lot and everyone is passing props to child like this. Kindly tell what am i missing

Parent:

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
  updateData = (data) => {
    console.log(`This data isn't parent data. It's ${data}.`)
    // data should be 'child data' when the
    // Test button in the child component is clicked
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <Child updateData={val => this.updateData(val)} />
    );
  }
```

Child:

```
class Child extends React.Component {
  const passedData = 'child data'
  handleClick = () => {
    this.props.updateData(passedData);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <button onClick={this.handleClick()}>Test</button>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
`class Child extends React.Component {    
    handleClick = () => {
        const passedData = 'child data'
        this.props.updateData(passedData);
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Test</button>
        );
    }
}`
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Parent extends React.Component { 
updateData = (data) => {
  console.log(`This data isn't parent data. It's ${data}.`)
}
render() {
  return (
    <Child updateData={this.updateData} />
  );
}
}
```

and child component: `

```
class Child extends React.Component {
  const passedData = 'child data'
  handleClick = () => {
    this.props.updateData(passedData);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Test</button>
    );
  }
}
```

`

Comment: I also tried to replace with navigation code like this.navigation.navigate('Screen1', {}) but still the same error. I don't know what to do now...

Comment: actually i am also having similar issue like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34860822/react-native-loop-this

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the function directly, not as a callback

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
  updateData = (data) => {
    console.log(`This data isn't parent data. It's ${data}.`)
    // data should be 'child data' when the
    // Test button in the child component is clicked
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <Child updateData={this.updateData} />
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to pass a function like this. [Check out this solution](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ebd2g8?file=index.js).

Comment: Please include some more details from the source you mentioned as  in future link may stop working to gets removed !